# Total variance of a complex measure equality without Radon nikodym theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory

If $ f \in L^{1}(X,\mu)$ and $ \mu_{f}(E) = \int_E \! f \, \mathrm{d}\mu $ for all $E \in M $
Prove that $|\mu_{f}| = \mu_{|f|}$ (without using Radon nikodym theorem and its consequences)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to show that $|\mu_f|\leq \mu_{f}$ and $\mu_{f}\leq |\mu_f|.$

Comment: I got it. $|\mu_{f}| \leq \mu_{|f|}$ because total variance is the least positive measure dominating complex measure $\mu_{f}$. The other inequality is kinda complicated to prove. But did it with the help of partitioning  X (or E) by splitting arg $f(x)$ into N equal intervals of $2 \pi$.